# Creating Authorisation Schemes with SQL and APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to make authorisation schemes in APEX for different roles such as:

```
Customers
Agents
Employees (IT Staff)
Employees (Database Admin)
Employees (Other)
```

I'm not sure how to go about it. My teacher used an EXIST SQL QUERY wherein an authorisation table was made like this:

```
CREATE TABLE authorisation (
user_id VARCHAR2(30),
privilege VARCHAR2(30)
 );
```

Then each user's id and privilege was inputted.

afterwards, the authorisation query would be something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM authorisation
WHERE user_id = :APP_USER AND
privilege = ‘ALL’
```

But I don't want to have to input every user's ID and authorisation. I know that everyone in the Customer table will have the same authorisation. Is there a way to make a query that allows everyone from a certain table to be authorised?

Answer (score 0):

Although you complain about what teacher suggested, I'd suggest the opposite - listen to what they said. The fact that - currently - everyone in some table have the same privilege,  can be changed *tomorrow* and you'll have a problem which can easily be avoided by creating additional table (`authorization`).

Doing so, I'd suggest you to create a stored function (or, perhaps even better, a package) which would return value that says whether someone has (or doesn't have) certain privilege.

For example (this is package body with only one function; create specification and other functions yourself):

```
create or replace package body pkg_authorization as
  function f_is_customer_01 (par_app_user in varchar2)
    return number 
  is
    retval number(1) := 0;
  begin
    select 1 into retval
      from authorization
      where user_id = par_app_user
        and privilege = 'CUSTOMER';

    return retval;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return retval;
  end;
end pkg_authorization;
```

So: if `:APP_USER` is a `customer`, function will return `1`, otherwise it'll return `0`. You could have created it to return Boolean - it works just fine, but - you can't use it in e.g. `select` statement, its `where` clause and similar.

How to use it? For example, if you want to display some region (or item) to someone who is customer, you'd create Server side condition whose type is a function that returns Boolean:

```
return pkg_authorization.f_is_customer_01(:APP_USER) = 1;
```

I use something like that as well; works just fine.